# JavaScript: ссылка на объект

Tags: объекты, javascript, ссылки

Добрый день. Немного не понимаю, как работают ссылки на объекты в javascript-е. Допустим, есть такой код:

```
var Car = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var cars = [new Car('BWM')],
    bmw = cars[0];

cars.splice(0,1);
console.log(bmw);
```

Есть функция Car и массив, где единственным элементом является объект Car. Далее присваеваем переменной bmw первый элемент массива, т.е. объект Car. На этом этапе, как я понимаю, bwm содержит ссылку на объект Car. Потом, мы удаляем объект из массива. Тут появляются вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что bmw по-прежнему обращается по адресу объекта, который был в массиве (т.е. в памяти новых объектов не появляется)? Если нет, то куда?
2. Создается ли в памяти новый объект bmw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, массив содержит не сами объекты, а лишь ссылки на них.

Соответственно удаление элемента из массива есть не более чем удаление одной из ссылок на объект. Объект всё ещё доступен по другим ссылкам, и не будет прихлопнут сборщиком мусора. Новый объект не создаётся.

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, если я создам пару тысяч переменных, ссылающихся на cars[0], то с точки зрения памяти это будет экономно, т.к. все они смотрят по конкретному адресу в памяти?

    bmw = cars[0];
    bmw2 = cars[0];
    bmw3 = cars[0];
    ...
    bwm1000 = cars[0];

Comment: @likerRr: Ну, размер объекта `Car` не такой уж и большой, т. е. размер ссылки сравним с размером объекта. Но в любом случае: все ссылки, да, будут смотреть на один и тот же объект.

Answer (score 2):

Как я это понимаю. Когда вы пишите `new Car('BWM')` где-то в памяти создается объект и ссылка на этот объект присваивается в переменную (в вашем примере эта ссылка привязывается к объекту (массивы это тоже объекты), который в свою очередь присваивается переменной cars). Далее вы просто присваиваете эту ссылку (на вашу машину) переменной bmw. Далее, если вы удалите все ссылки на какой либо объект, объект удаляется из памяти. То есть, если вы напишете `cars = 'wonderfull'`, после присвоения массива, то вашему массива торба (удаляется из памяти, все ссылки удалены), но объект, на который ссылается `bmw` жив, так как на него еще хоть что-то ссылается. Почитайте Флэнагана по этому поводу, он более доступно расписал этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, боюсь это будет не столь актуальным, т.к. сейчас браузеры используют иную реализацию сборщика мусора по принципу "mark and sweep"